# In Safari on iPad is there a way to stop the page rubber banding BUT still allow overflows too scroll?

Tags: javascript, ipad, mobile-safari, overflow, touchmove

There's a lot of snippets to stop the rubber-banding on iPad, like the one below:

```
document.body.addEventListener('touchmove',function(event){ event.preventDefault(); },false);
```

However this has the unwanted effect of preventing all divs with overflows on them from scrolling too?

Is there a way to just top the page (body) from rubber-banding while still allowing the overflowed-scrolled  divs to do so?

Answer (score 1):

The rubber-banding of the entire page seems to happen when the user is scrolling from the very bottom or very top of a div. The code I've written checks to see if the user is indeed at one of those extremes and if so prevents the scrolling action from happening in those directions.

```
elem.bind("touchstart", function( e )
{
    xStart = e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0].screenX;
    yStart = e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0].screenY;
});

elem.bind("touchmove", function( e )
{
    var xMovement = e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0].screenX - xStart;
    var yMovement = e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0].screenY - yStart;

    if( elem.scrollTop() == (elem[0].scrollHeight - elem[0].clientHeight) && yMovement < 0 )
    {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    else if( elem.scrollTop() == 0 && yMovement > 0 )
    {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Update: including the working jsfiddle demo link: http://jsfiddle.net/qQHrM/1/

Comment: That's funny...works perfectly for me. Maybe I misunderstood your question. Here's a working fiddle demo. http://jsfiddle.net/qQHrM/1/ On my ipad I'm able to scroll the div, but if I reach one of the ends the page doesn't rubber band.